# Storing additional user details with ASP.NET Membership

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership

I'm new to ASP.NET Membership, and previously created login systems from scratch by creating a table such as:

```
Users
-----
ID
Username
Password
Email
AddressLine1
AddressLine2
Town
County
Country
Mobile
```

With the `aspnet_users` table I see there are no Address fields etc.

What is the best practice for adding this additional information? Would it make sense to edit the `aspnet_users` table and the related Stored Procedures, or would it be better to create a second table, such as `users_details` which has a Foreign Key relating to the `aspnet_users` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i guess you can find, what you are looking for: [Storing Additional User Information](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-cs)

Answer (score 1):

asp.net has this already built in. You can do this by using the [User Profile Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx)